# How to divide a row of text into multiple columns based on the delimiter ';' in Unix?

Tags: csv, unix

I've a csv file with hundreds of rows. It looks as follows:

```
Ž|12340525;AXN003    ;57DJ348;Z;2213-06;888;Bughekh_SEGikh        ;1234        ;S87_3   ;ABCD_1234     ;
Ž|67890323;TYN003    ;H46DOE8;Z;2342-05;888;uRVGFVi_THFHIH        ;3421        ;D45_1   ;ERTT_8432     ;
```

Now, I need the illegal characters before the first pipe `|` to be removed and the record should be divided into multiple columns with `;` as the delimiter along with the empty spaces present before `;` removed.
The above records would look like follows after achieving what I need:

```
Col1        Col2       Col3      Col4   Col5       Col6   Col7              Col8     Col9    Col10
12340525;    AXN003;   57DJ348;   Z;    2213-06;   888;   Bughekh_SEGikh;   1234;   S87_3;   ABCD_1234;
67890323;    TYN003;   H46DOE8;   Z;    2342-05;   888;   uRVGFVi_THFHIH;   3421;   D45_1;   ERTT_8432;
```

How do I achieve this in Unix and also export the formatted data into a CSV file?

I'm very new to Unix and require help on this one, please!

Comment: This isn't a unix specific question though it could be accomplished with shell tools, it might not be the most suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you need using a combination of `cut` and `sed`. Assuming your input is a file called `input.txt`

```sh
cat input.txt | cut -d'|' -f2- | sed 's/\s*;/;\t/g'

12340525;   AXN003; 57DJ348;    Z;  2213-06;    888;    Bughekh_SEGikh; 1234;   S87_3;  ABCD_1234;  
67890323;   TYN003; H46DOE8;    Z;  2342-05;    888;    uRVGFVi_THFHIH; 3421;   D45_1;  ERTT_8432;
```

For .csv output, simply change the replacement character to `,` instead of `\t`

```sh
cat input.txt | cut -d'|' -f2- | sed 's/\s*;/,/g'

12340525,AXN003,57DJ348,Z,2213-06,888,Bughekh_SEGikh,1234,S87_3,ABCD_1234,
67890323,TYN003,H46DOE8,Z,2342-05,888,uRVGFVi_THFHIH,3421,D45_1,ERTT_8432,
```

Note that you will either have a trailing `,` or trailing `\t` in the above solutions but stripping those out would be trivial.